# Responsive side menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, sidenav

I am following a tutorial titled 'Responsive HTML & CSS Side Menu From Scratch' by Traversy Media on Youtube (I'd post the link by not enough reputation yet) and I am having a couple of issues with my side-nav. Note the way that it appears [before I click on the openSlideMenu() icon on the top left-hand corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTCCy.png) versus when [I have clicked on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXmGT.png). I have followed the teacher's code to-the-t, yet there appears to be at least 4 problems on the interface.

1. There is an open tag symbol positioned near the 3-bar icon that remains both when the menu is up and when it is not.
2. The side-nav, when clicked to open, goes far away from the left side of the page, creating a large whitespace gap between the menu and the left-side of the page, where no gap should exist.
3. The side-nav goes over the title text 'Responsive Side Menu', thus blocking the 'e Menu' part of the text, whereas the title text should be responsive and move when the side-nav moves, as portrayed in the tutorial.
4. The closeMenuButton() within the side-nav has its position straight over the elements whereas it should be positioned in the right hand corners.

My HTML/Javascript Code:

```js
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.marginLeft = '250px';
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0px';
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.marginLeft = '0px';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", Serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 63px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}

.side-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.side-nav a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.side-nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.side-nav .btn-close {
  postion: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 22px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

# main {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

@media(max-width: 568px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="open-slide">
      <a href="#" onClick="openSlideMenu()">
        <<svg width="30" height="30">
          <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke=#fff stroke-width="5"/>
          <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke=#fff stroke-width="5"/>
          <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke=#fff stroke-width="5"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </span>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" onClick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <h1>Responsive Side Menu</h1>
    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Additionally, the teacher has the code that he produced in the description of his video on Youtube, which you can find as the first result by searching 'Responsive HTML & CSS Side Menu From Scratch'.

Comment: Your `<link` tag on `<head>` is broken

Comment: `<<svg width="30" height="30">` has an extra `<` at the beginning.

Comment: You also have an extra `<` in front of `<svg ...`

Comment: Oh wow, that was really quick. Okay, I fixed both the extra < in front of svg and the link tag, but I still have the same issues as before.

Answer (score 0):

The code was full of mistakes 
Here is the working code
Find your mistakes

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style media="screen">
    body {
      font-family: "Arial", Serif;
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .navbar {
      background-color: #3b5998;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 63px;
    }

    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .navbar ul {
      margin: 8px 0 0 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: #000;
    }

    .side-nav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      opacity: 0.9;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      margin-top: 60px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .side-nav a {
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #ccc;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .side-nav a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .side-nav .btn-close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 22px;
      font-size: 36px;
      display: inline;
    }

    #main {
      transition: margin-left 0.5s;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .open-slide {
      display: none;
    }

    @media(max-width: 568px) {
      .navbar-nav {
       display: none
      }
      .open-slide {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="open-slide">
      <a href="#" onClick="openSlideMenu()">
        <<svg width="30" height="30">
          <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke=#fff stroke-width="5"/>
          <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke=#fff stroke-width="5"/>
          <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke=#fff stroke-width="5"/>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </span>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" onClick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <h1>Responsive Side Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openSlideMenu() {
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
    }

    function closeSlideMenu() {
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0px';
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.marginLeft = '0px';
    }
    </script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: That code is not working. My 3-bar icon is completely missing with that code. Additionally, I no longer can access my side menu.

Comment: @Devon You 3-bar icon is meant for small devices. Just resize the window it will become visible. And I have checked every thing is working fine

Comment: You know what? This might be better formatting than what was provided in the tutorial, as a sidebar might not necessarily be useful for a full webpage, but it certainly is for a phone. Although this being the case, I'm sure I'll probably ask about a sidebar for a full-size web page sometime down the line but for now this will work well. Thank you.

Comment: @Devon Your are welcome. Make sure you upvote and accept if this answer was helpful

Comment: Also, I do still have issues with the closeMenuButton() being positioned in the center of my side menu rather than in the right hand corner, as well as with the weird tag < thing that still appears. I may ask StackOverflow for help on this in the future, referencing this question thread.